# Web page scrolling is disabled after google maps api

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, scroll

I have a one page site I am working on for my small company. I have added a google maps div to contact tab. Everything seems normal but when I try to scroll the page down to see whatever below, it does not work/scroll. Below is a link for my website (Please try on mozilla or ie to see what I actually mean.):

www.hidroturbin.com/htonepage

I tried the "disable scrollwheel option" in the map options of js code:

scrollwheel: false

This time scrolling was disabled for both the gmaps and the page.

I could not find a way. I am searching for almost 2 days and about to go nuts.

Anyone here to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have overflow: hidden; on your body, just remove it from your css file htonepage.css

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the correction but still the same. Btw I figured out something: Whether overflow is hidden or not, if I close google maps infowindow, scrolling works. I do not know why.

Comment: well for me it's still the same on firefox and chrome, I tried to remove the overflow:hidden and it works fine (you didn't change it on prod ?)

Answer (score 0):

can you try to modify the code and IMO this will work

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
       this.setOptions({scrollwheel:true});
  });
```